# Grant Permissions Within Report SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

Leaving aside *why* one would want to do such a thing:

In MS SQL Server 2008, Is it possible to have a report SP grant permissions to a column used in that report to a table in a database other than the one it's running in?

I'm looking at something like the following:

```
USE mydb
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.report 
AS
BEGIN
GRANT SELECT ON otherdb.dbo.table (column) TO [myuser]

SELECT * from otherdb.dbo.table
END
```

Execute cannot be used on objects in a db other than the current one and USE statements cannot be included within a stored procedure. Is there another way?

Comment: If you're just trying to access data the a report user doesn't have access to you may be able to use EXECUTE AS https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the same user exists in both databases:

```
EXEC otherdb.sys.sp_executesql N'GRANT ...';
```

Of course you grant SELECT on a column, not EXECUTE.